# Adding custom link in the beginning of the top.links section using default.xml

Tags: magento2, default.xml

I have created a custom link using default.xml and moved it inside the top.links reference block.
This is my code

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-top-link-blog">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Blog</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">#</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I have also made some changes to top.links block.

```
<move element="register-link" destination="top.links"/>
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="minicart"/>
```

This is what I have achieved. Plz check the screenshot.
[image]

Now I need to move my custom link "Blog" before My Account that is in the first position. Screenshot where I need it.
[image]

How I can achieve this. I have tried adding before="-" in this line

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-top-link-blog" before="-">
```

but it did not worked. Plz suggest how I can achieve this.

**Update:** I have tried a solution according to the suggestion in comment but it did not worked.
I found the block name for My Account section. I found it inside the module-customer default.xml file. This was the code.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sign up</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
               template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Then I used this block name in my custom theme default.xml file to change the position of Blog but it did not worked. This was the code that I added in default.xml file.

```
<move element="custom-top-link-blog" destination="top.links" before="my-account-link"/>
```

Plz let me know a solution to achieve this as I am stuck in this.

Comment: You just need to find "My account" reference block name in your theme's file.And after that you need to add that reference block name in before="My account reference block". It should be work.

Comment: @ZealousWeb I have tried a solution according to your suggestion but it did not worked, plz have a look.

Comment: please add this and check - <move element="custom-top-link-blog" destination="top.links" before=''-"/>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why changing the position of my custom link did not work, but then I solved this by removing my custom link from top.links section and adding it to header-wrapper and then assigning the position.

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-top-link-blog" template="Magento_Theme::blog-link.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```